# Brute-Force GPU Password Crackers

Tags: passwords, brute-force, gpu

Brute-force password cracker programs which claim GPU support include John the Ripper, ighashgpu,  oclHashcat, and others.  oclHashcat appears one of the more popular, but I am not sure which AMD/ATI GPUs it supports. (I have an ATI card.)

Which of the password cracker programs has the greatest ATI GPU support?

Which is the easiest to use as an API library?

Which is the most reliable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which Hash your trying to crack. If its MD4/5 i'd go ighashgpu, for anything else, OCL-hashcat-plus

OCL-HashCat-Plus supports [these hashes](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-plus/#features-algos) and ATI/Nvidia cards on linux and Windows and has an excellent reputation, active forums and i've personally used it to great success on both Nvidia and ATI platforms. It's also updated regularly.

I've also used ighashgpu for MD5 cracking. It claims to be the worlds fastest multihash MD5 cracker for MD5. From comparisons i've read, i believe it to be true. The downside is that IghashGPU only supports SHA1, MD5 and MD4 hashes. Additionally, i odn't think its been updated for 2-3 years.

Both are equally reliable as long as your hardware is stable in my experience.

Additionally, since both are command line based (ocl-hashcat plus has an optional GUI), its easy to incorporate them into a script.

Comment: would you happen to know which ATI cards HashCat supports, or at least a link? The readme says "AMD users require Catalyst 13.1 -exact-" and "- All CUDA and Stream enabled cards should work". That's it.

Comment: @T.Webster What card are you currently running?

Comment: nevermind, [here](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-919.html) is the answer.

Comment: would you mind having a look at this thread? http://hashcat.net/forum/thread-2317.html

Comment: The thread has a pretty definite answer of 'No'. There's no support for integration with other applications at this stage.